# In React-Native i am unable to convert the blob to URL I keep getting [Error: Cannot create URL for blob!]

Tags: react-native, blob

I have a backend system which stores videos and other data, I have an API which fetches the video using a POST request as blob.

In react native I am not able to obtain the bite array and keep getting this response

"{"_data": {"__collector": {}, "blobId": "355eea50-07a4-498c-a0a1-83687467888e", "offset": 0, "size": 80}}"

```
  await axios({
        method: "POST",
        url: forumServerIP + 'api',
        data: jsonData,
        responseType: 'blob',
    })
        .then( async (response) =>  {
            const blob = await response.data;
            const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
            console.log(url)
            
        })
        .catch(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        });}
```

How do I fix this, I am on the latest react native version 0.71.2

Comment: Would you be able to post the code that you're utilizing in your app to fetch the blob data?

Comment: I have added the code snippet